# SaveAs Default path

Tags: vba, excel, save-as

I have a macro in my excel and when I use .SaveAs in said macro, it automatically saves the file in my documents (when I dont specify a path)

I really dont want to specify a path, I just want it to save the resulting file in the directoy where excel book is.

heres the save code:

```
    fnameandpath = InputBox("Please Enter A New File Name")
    If fnameandpath = Empty Then
        'warn user

    Else  
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs fnameandpath
        Range("A1").Activate
    End If
```

so for example, I put my excel file on my desktop. I enter in "TestFile" when the box pops, then I get an xlsm file in `my documents` rather than on my desktop. Why? Can I change that default behavior? the msdn says it saves to the current location.

Comment: You can use `ThisWorkbook.Path` to get the folder containing the workbook where the macro runs

Comment: Do you know why it saves in my docs though? msdn says `Filename
Optional
Variant
A string that indicates the name of the file to be saved. You can include a full path; if you don't, Microsoft Excel saves the file in the current folder.` but desktop is the current folder... documents isnt even open

Comment: `current folder` is typically the last one you opened something from, or saved something to from within Excel.

Comment: right. desktop. I close all folders, I'm at the desktop, I open excel, i run the macro, I save and close, the file has saved in my documents. I even navigated through computer - desktop and ran my file that way... same deal

Comment: For me: open Excel, open a file from a specific folder (by choosing `open` and navigating to the file), close that file. Create new file in Excel, go to "save as" - defaults to the folder I opened that first file from.

Comment: In the options of Excel 2003 there is a place where you can put the default folder path.  I have never changed it and it is pointing to "C:\Users\Username\Documents".  Maybe this is the default path value used in your case.

Comment: I have excel 2010 and I was looking for something like that but couldnt find it, I'll look again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not that anyone is ever going to look at this but, there is indeed a default save path in excel. for 2010 anyways its options - save - default file location. the default is the documents folder.